# Is double comparsion safe when used as INotifyPropertyChanged property?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

Usually you can't be confident of checking the equality of two different doubles. What about a double property when using `INotifyPropertyChange`?

Is the following likely to cause any problems for  `if (this.optionXYZ != value)` or is this safe to use?

```
private double optionXYZ;
public double OptionXYZ
{
    get { return this.optionXYZ; }
    set
    {
        if (this.optionXYZ != value)
        {
            this.optionXYZ = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyOf<OptionSettings>.Resolve(x => x.OptionXYZ));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: optionXYZ is just a field of type double.  I can't see any reason why that would be a problem.

Comment: Why do you think `INotifyPropertyChange` helps to resolve an issue with nature of floating point computatiion arithmetics?

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser - I wanted to make sure the INotifyPropertyChange doesn't keep firing as the equality check would never be equal due to rounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of `double` comparison, this line:

```
if (this.optionXYZ != value)
```

doesn't make much sense because of nature of floating point numbers and special values like `NaN`.

But the only "problem" here is extra-raising of `PropertyChanged` event. Actually, this is not a problem, and has nothing to do with "safety".

About your sample - I'd remove equality checking at all.